# Help using Cjc.ChromiumBrowser .NET wrapper for Google Chrome

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, chromium, awesomium

I need some help using a .NET Wrapper for Google chrome. The problem is that I managed to find its DLLs and am using them in my project. They seem to run and all, but when I try to compile a release version, the application does not work.

In simple words, the DLL I have works for debug, but not for release! What do I do? Please help me. The wrapper is called Chromium Browser and was found here.
http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/wpf-chromium-webbrowser-source-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about why it "doesn't work", have you tried downloading the latest version of project from Codeplex? Links below.

- .NET 3.5: http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/
- .NET 4.0: http://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/

Also, something of note: I'm no longer certain of the license of the Codeplex project as it uses the *Awesomium* wrapper which has recently been released as a commercial product (http://awesomium.com/).

I recently looked at this product for an application that I'm writing and was able to compile .NET 3.5 source in Debug and Release without issue; I did not continue using it as I found a better solution (for my needs) using a `FlowDocument` and Microsoft HTML to XAML converter (it is an MSDN example).